# One element of list view should not swipe

Tags: android

I am using onswipelistener in list view in android. Is it possible that one element of the list does not swipe.
I.e. when I swipe that particular element from  left to right only that element should not swipe and the images below it should not appear. While the rest of element should appear. Is it possible in android.

Comment: Yes, possible. But you have to code for that.

Comment: Yes, i agree with @Gunaseelan but you have to take one flag (isSwipeable) for each item and set flag true/false value  base on list item index wise.

Comment: Need guidance. I will set isSwipeable = false for particular element. Then how android will know that if I do swipe gesture on the element, it should not swipe.  Can u give me more details how to achieve it.